# Clarification on Running Time Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

Question: Using the detailed method of analysis of the running time of algorithms, how many times does the following for-loop executes?

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
```

Answer: The total running time for the for-loop is `τfetch+ τstore + (n+1)(2τfetch+ τ<) + n(2τfetch + τ+ + τstore)`

Can somebody please explain to me why in the answer we have `(2τfetch+ τ<)` instead of `(2τfetch+ τ≤)`?

I have attempted to do it on my own and I understand it but the part in question is the one I don't quite get.